# How can I make order editable linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

On youtube app's playlist menu, there are some bars that enables you to change orders of youtube's videos smoothly.
I wanted to make it, but I don't know how.

Is it able to make that with linearlayout? If not, what layout I have to use and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you looking for is **Recyclerview with drag and drop feature**. You cannot do it with linearlayout.
You have to use recyclerview and ItemTouchHelper to acheive this.